# subsub document id returns whole document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I findOne based on deliverables.steps._id it's returning my entire document rather than just my step with the particular id.  Can I not have it return my individual step rather than the whole document?  The reason I ask is so when I need to update I just update this step rather than updating the whole document each time.

```
exports.findStep = function(req, res) { 
    Project.findOne({'deliverables.steps._id': req.params.stepId}).sort('-created').exec(function(err, step) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({

                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(step);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/. Updates in MongoDB affect the whole document unless you use the $set operator. You query an array, so you'll need the position of the element for updating it.

Comment: but how do I pull out just the single step to manipulate the data ?  Right now it's just pulling the whole document even though I'm specifying a sub-sub document to find.

Comment: Should be something like `find({'deliverables.steps._id': req.params.stepId}, {_id:1, 'deliverables.$':1, otherFieldYouDoNotWant: 0})`. But it won't return you the position of the element. So in the end I fear, you have to fetch the whole document when reading.

Comment: Another option is to reconsider data structure and have a separate collection for steps, each of which will be related to certain deliverable by id. At least, it should better scale.